# How can $4$ points in the plane be vertices of $3$ different quadrilaterals?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

> Four points on the plane are vertices of three different quadrilaterals. How can this happen?

The problem is taken from "Kiselev's Geometry - Book I : Planimetry"

At first, I thought it could be like this :

[image]

But, the way diagonals are defined in the book:

[image]

Makes me think that the 3 figures I drew, are the same quadrilateral.

How do you think four points on the plane can be vertices of three different quadrilaterals

Comment: Let A, B, C, D be the vertices. Then ABCD, ACDB, ADBC are three different quadrilaterals. The roles of sides and diagonals are not the same in them: there are 6 segments, and you can choose any two of them as diagonals, as long as they share no vertex (three possibilities to do so).

Answer (score 18):

Is this what you mean by three different quadrilaterals?
[image]

Answer (score 10):

One point (say D) is inside the triangle formed by the other three (ABC). Then the possible quadrilaterals are ABCD, ABDC or ADBC.

Comment: Your first sentence is not necessarily true. It fails (at least, but not only) for any convex quadrilateral.

Comment: It is if the "three quadrilaterals" aren't allowed to be self-intersecting, which I imagine is the intended interpretation.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is a possible interpretation. I would see no problem with a self-intersecting quadrilateral, but I don't know the intent of the author. So +1 after all :)